# Uploading chunked files with JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Weyooo,

I know this topic has been discussed here, but something strange is happening when i try it. Here comes de code and then i will explain what is happening.

JS:

```
var Form = document.getElementById("Upload");
var FileSelect = document.getElementById("inputFile");    

Form.onsubmit = function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var Blob = FileSelect.files[0];      
  const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1048576;
  const SIZE = Blob.size;
  var Start = 0;
  var End = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;

    while (Start < SIZE) {

      var Chunk = Blob.slice(Start, End);
      uploadFile(Chunk);
      Start = End;
      End = Start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;

    }

};

function uploadFile(blobFile) {

  var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("inputFile", blobFile);

    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

          XHR.onload = function(e) {

            console.log("Loaded!");

          };

          XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {

            console.log(this.responseText);

          };

            XHR.open("POST", "upload.php");

            XHR.send(formData);

}
```

PHP:

```
$target_path = "storage/";
$tmp_name = $_FILES['inputFile']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['inputFile']['size'];
$name = $_FILES['inputFile']['name'];

$complete = "asd.png";
$com = fopen("storage/".$complete, "a");

$in = fopen($tmp_name, "r");

if ($in) {

  while ($buff = fread( $in, 1048576 )) {

    fwrite($com, $buff);

  }

}

fclose($in);

fclose($com);
```

I have tested both codes separately and works fine. When i upload separately, first i upload the 5 chunks of 1 MB done with the JS code and then i put all together with the PHP code, and works like a charm.

The problem comes when i put all together and i try to upload a file. For example, if i take a png image of 5 MB of size and i execute the code, the result file will be a 2.32 MB image.

Therefore, it come to my mind that maybe the problem of all, is that the JS code is uploading the bolb file before the previous one has been written with the PHP code, therefore results a file which is corrupted. Is this possible? Is there any error? Thanks!

Comment: `Therefore, it come to my mind that maybe the problem of all, is that the JS code is uploading the bolb file before the previous one has been written`..  Correct, . `uploadFile(Chunk);`  will not wait.. You need to send the next chunck on your `XHR.onload` callback.  ps. This would all be a lot easier if you use Promises / async / await..

Comment: Actually it was. So thanks!